# How to assign a value for a column based on another column value in R?

Tags: r, merge, data-munging

I have a dataframe

```
 df <- data.frame(structure(list(col1= c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A"), 
         col2= c(1, 1, 1, 1, 5), col3 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)),
         .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3"), 
         row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"))
```

I want to add additional column, col4 with values based on col2. Rows that have the same value in col2 will have the same value in col4 as well.

With a work around, I generated a result in the following way.

```
x <- df[!duplicated(df$col2),]
x$col4 <- paste("newValue", seq(1:nrow(x)), sep="_")

df_new <- merge(x, df, by ="col2")

df_new <- df_new[,c("col2","col4", "col1.y", "col3.y")]
```

This works but I thought there is a better way doing this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this helps

```
df$col4 <- paste0("newValue_", cumsum(!duplicated(df$col2)))
df$col4
#[1] "newValue_1" "newValue_1" "newValue_1" "newValue_1" "newValue_2"
```

Or we use `match`

```
with(df, paste0("newValue_", match(col2, unique(col2))))
#[1] "newValue_1" "newValue_1" "newValue_1" "newValue_1" "newValue_2"
```

Or it can be done with `factor`

```
with(df, paste0("newValue_", as.integer(factor(col2, levels = unique(col2)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try `dense_rank()` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(col4 = dense_rank(col2),
           col4_new = paste0("newValue_", col4))
```

This gives something very similar to your desired output in your question, but I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for. If you want to ensure that *all* rows with identical values in `col2` get the same value in `col4` then just `arrange` the `df` and then use `dense_rank` :

```
df %>% 
    arrange(col2) %>% 
    mutate(col4 = dense_rank(col2),
           col4_new = paste0("newValue_", col4))
```

This should work for a `data.frame` of arbitrary size.